# How to update a bar chart with d3.js correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For several days now, I'm trying to update my bar chart. I know that I use enter() to initialize the chart and transition() to update the values. Unfortunately it just doesn't work. 
Also I read, that I have to "bind" data via return(d), so I can update it.
Im using Eclipse, so my js code won't produce any error messages which makes it nearly impossible for me to understand whats going on since I'm not realy familiar with js.

_targetDiv and myDiv are exactly the same and _data has the right values.

I'll only post the methods adressing the issue. 
If I call addUpdatedChart(_data, _targetDiv) the whole JSP is frozen. 
If I comment it out, or don't call it, it's the same.
If I delete it, it compiles at least.

Any clues, what I'm doing wrong?

```
        //Add chart to the tracker
        function addChart(myDiv)
        {
            //Create div
            var barDiv = document.createElement("div");
            barDiv.id = String(myDiv.id + "chart");
            barDiv.style.position= "absolute";
            barDiv.style.width = "20px";
            barDiv.style.height = "20px";
            myDiv.appendChild(barDiv);

            //Enter()
            var data = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];

            //Create bar chart
            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#C0C0C0", "#FFCC00", "#FF3399", "#CCFFCC", "#CCFF66", "#CCFF00"]);
            var height = 10;

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
                .range([0, 100]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(height)])
                .range([0, height]);

            d3.select(String("#" + myDiv.id))
              .selectAll("div")
                .data(data)
              .enter().append("div")
                .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
                .style("height", function(d) { return y(d) + "px"; })
                .style("background-color", function(d, i) {return color(i);})
                .style("font-size","10px")
                .style("opacity", 1.0)//Cant be below 1.0?
                .text(function(d) { return d; });
        }




        //Values for the chart update
        function addUpdatedChart(_data, _targetDiv)
        {
            //Update bar chart
            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#C0C0C0", "#FFCC00", "#FF3399", "#CCFFCC", "#CCFF66", "#CCFF00"]);
            var height = 10;

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(_data)])
                .range([0, 100]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(height)])
                .range([0, height]);

            d3.select(String("#" + _targetDiv))
              .selectAll("div")
                .data(_data)
              .transition().duration(1500)
                .style("width", x + "px")
                .style("height", y + "px")
                .style("background-color", color(i))
                .style("font-size","10px")
                .style("opacity", 1.0)//Cant be below 1.0?
                .text();
        }
```

Comment: First at all: remove or comment out: var varDiv = ....... ppendChild(barDiv); here de jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spsqmy5s/

Comment: I guess this is only so the fiddle works? Since I'll create the divs onClick() in my app...